# How to show message in Popup without reloading the page in Laravel? I am sending data using CURL

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is `dashboard.blade.php` My View.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('/dashboard/validate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset style="height: auto;">
            <legend>Complaint Details</legend>
            <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="pnr">PNR/Unreserved Tickets No <span class="errors">*</span>: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">          
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="pnr" id="pnr" placeholder="PNR/Unreserved Tickets No." required>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my `DashboardController.php`

```
public function formSubmit(Request $request){
    $data1 = [
        'name'=> $passName,
  ];
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "xyz.com",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$data1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
          ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Error on submitting form.');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Thank You for Submitting Complaint');
    }
}
```

It is working fine. I am sending the data through CURL in Laravel. I just want to not refresh the page after submitting the Form. I just want to show the Successful message or error message in a popup. When I am submitting the form, It reloads the page. I just don't want to reload the page.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Then use Ajax!!

Comment: I am using CURL because the API has some restrictions. Is there any way to CURL code only.@MahdiYounesi

Comment: pretty sure @MahdiYounesi meant to say, use ajax in your front end to send the request to the `formSubmit` function. using that function kinda of like a bridge between your front end and that api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get information from controller through Ajax on page load.  And success response replace content using jquery.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page after submitting the Form. I just want to show the message in Popup.@Narayan Sharma

Comment: @Raghav just use jQuery onload page event. On that event hit Ajax to your controller and controller give you some response. That response code will be available inside success call back method in Ajax.

Comment: That will prevent you from page load.

Comment: Can you Code??@Narayan Sharma

Comment: Yes. But you have to follow lots of things to do. Do you know Ajax?

Comment: Follow my steps. I can help you out to solve this problem.

Comment: Okay.@Narayan Sharma

Comment: for Ajax onload event : follow this https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167729/discussion-between-raghav-and-narayan-sharma).